# C# BinaryReader working weird

Tags: c#, methods, io, stream

When I call `ReadByte`, an overridden `Read` method is executed.

Code is here

```
public object Read(Stream s)
{
    Issues.Clear();

    if (AutoReset)
        Reset();

    using (var r = new BinaryReader(s, Encoder, true))
    {
        // check stream begin
        if (r.ReadByte() != StreamBegin) // this r.ReadByte() goto..
        {
```

Here I call `ReadByte`. This `BinaryReader` is from `System.IO`.

And next `ReadByte()` method go to here

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    ..... Something
}
```

This method is in a custom class.

Call stack is here:

[image]

So.. why does this happen? Why does this code work like this?

Comment: `ReadByte()` is apparently implemented in terms of `Read(byte[],int,int)`. Is that really a big surprise to you?

Comment: what class is that override in?  it's normal for `ReadByte()` to call `Read(byte[], int, int)` in it's code, since all `ReadByte()` does is read the next byte then advance the stream.  There would be no real advantage for `ReadByte` to implement it's own version of the `Read` code....

Comment: @Jeff Mercado,Clasies  ReadByte is called from  "public class InstanceSerializer" "namespace EMx.Serialization" and Read method called by ReadByte is on "public class MxStream" "namespace EMx.IO.MxData". and "public class InstanceSerializer" didnt using "EMx.IO.MxData" . I want to know how these independent class work together?

Answer (score 0):

ReadByte() call Read() and move position to next. So Read() method is overrided in custom class so ReadByte() go to overrided Read() method.